# JUnit terminate after time with success

Tags: java, junit

Is there an annotation which would allow my test to terminate with success after a time period? Lets say I want the test to pass after 10 seconds of run time.

Where this feature could be useful? For the sake of an abstract example lets say I have programmed an robot which has to balance a stick on his hand for at least 10 seconds or play Atari Breakout for a minute after some machine learning (and I want to automatically check whether it is trained well enough without having to watch it).

I know the `@Test` annotation has a `timeout` parameter, but it only allows me to terminate the test with failure after some running time. So is it possible to run tests which pass after a time period? I'm looking for something like this, but using annotations (obviously for the same reason why there is a `timeout` parameter):

```
@Test
public void timeoutTest() {
    Date begin = new Date();
    Robot robot = new Robot(new AtariBreakout());
    robot.play();
    Date end = new Date();
    Assert.assertTrue(end.getTime() - begin.getTime() >= 10000)
}
```

Why I can't just use it, and be happy with the solution? Because It uses the assumption, that the robot plays the game for about ten seconds and not lets say 2 hours. After a night of extensive testing I don't want to wake up with only one of 100 tests executed, because the robot was too well programmed.

**Edit:**

One of the comments directed me to a "solution", which happens to be completely wrong and fails on the following code:

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
        while (true)
            System.out.println("HaHa");
    });
    thread.run();
    assert (thread.isAlive());
    thread.stop();
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    while (true);
}
```

If `test2()` runs after `test1()` it still produces the output as if it was still runnig. Tests performed on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. The funny part is, that it's still producing output after terminating the tests, so the only thing that happened - it just launched a slowly growing fork bomb which increased in size every time the tests were run.

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741710/how-to-get-a-success-with-junit-and-timeout

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted - It's just a workaround. To do this I'd have to run the `Robot` in another thread and I'd have to implement another method to the robot which checks whether it's still running.

Comment: Ok, I forgot about the `isAlive()` method. But I'm looking for something like the `timeout` parameter of the `@Test` annotation, because it's handy and it wouldn't have to write that much boilerplate (creating a new thread with new runnable, running the thread, make the test thread sleep and adding an assertion), because a test should be the best and most up to date part of the documentation. Adding boilerplate like this makes it less readable (I mean the boilerplate would literally overpass the test length which is `robot.play()`.

Comment: JUnit does not support such kinds of test out of the box. You have to build something by yourself. JUnit has two extension points: `Runner` and `TestRule`. Maybe you can use them.

Comment: I believe this is the needed feature.